# Python vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method

Tags: python

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('num', 'pass')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

vk.messages.send(user_id='252982966',message='Проверка бота.')
```

Scope прописывал. Не помогло. Что делать?

Comment: API сообщений давным-давно закрыт, исправить это невозможно

Comment: А давным-давно это когда? Года назад помню работало)

Answer (score 2):

Доступ к сообщениям через API с недавнего времени закрыт